# Django - using generic views

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use Django generic view for CRUD.

I found two resources ([1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial04/), [2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)), and bit confused the best and easy approach.

1. Added below to myapp/urls.py

> ```
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>     url(r'^$',
>         ListView.as_view(
>             model= Product)),
> )
> ```

then it gave an error that,

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
myapp/product_list.html
```

It worked when I created a file product_list.html. But, do I have to manually write the template? I am sure not.

Also, how to decorate it so that only users of a group has access to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator can be applied inside the urlpatterns like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', my_decorator(ListView.as_view(model= Product))),
)
```

Yes you have to manually write the template.
Also the name of the template is the_model_name_list.html by default but you can also define a custom template name like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', my_decorator(ListView.as_view(model= Product,
                                             template_name="custom_name.html"))),
)
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch. is there a way to extend the admin template. Basically, I like to use the admin template, but as a non-admin user. thanks gain.

Comment: This [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) can help you on this.